# Dynamically create table and rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

How can I create a table dynamically and then add rows to the table? I have been able to create the table with one row with form fields, but how I can add additional rows? Any example on how it has been implement would helpful. I did in angular 2.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OoyT.png)

```
$scope.newItem = function($event, valI) {
  $scope['questionelemnt'].push({   
    id: counter, 
    title: '',
    desc: '',
    Qty: '', 
    price: '',
    total: ''
  }); 
}
```

Any help in angular or jquery.

Comment: How did you do it for one row?  Can you not just do the same again?

Comment: By $scope['questionelemnt'].push. Learned from http://jsfiddle.net/JDS2U/22/. Replaced it as table. Is there any jsfiddle where table and rows can been dynamically added and removed

Comment: please specify what exactly is the problem,   if you want to create tables dynamically,  or rows or both?

Comment: Yes, Both table and rows. Have added screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directive ng-app & ng-controller code
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html ng-app="helloApp">
   <head>
   <title>Hello AngularJS - Add Table Row Dynamically</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"   href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
   <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- Controller name goes here -->
<body ng-controller="CompanyCtrl">
...
</body>
</html>

Controller CompanyCtrl code in controller.js            
<script>
var helloApp = angular.module("helloApp", []);
helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.questions = [];
$scope.addRow = function(){     
    $scope.questions.push({ 'title':$scope.title, 'desc': $scope.desc,  'Qty':$scope.Qty,'price':$scope.price,'total':$scope.total });
    $scope.title='';
    $scope.desc='';
    $scope.Qty='';
    $scope.price='';
    $scope.total='';
};
)};
</script>
 Directive ng-repeat code
 <table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>title
    </th>
    <th>desc
    </th>
    <th> Qty
    </th>
    <th>price
    </th>
   <th>total
    </th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <td>{ {question.title}}
    </td>
    <td>{ {question.desc}}
    </td>
    <td>{ {question.Qty}}
    </td>
    <td>{ {question.price}}
    </td>
     <td>{ {question.total}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

**Directive ng-submit code**

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">title</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"
            ng-model="title" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">desc</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc"
            ng-model="desc" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Qty</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Qty"
            ng-model="Qty" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">price</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"
            ng-model="price" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">total</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total"
            ng-model="total" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                
    <div style="padding-left:110px">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Happy Coding ,Hope it will help you

Comment: Please read why [it isn't wise to post code-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/341145)